# Not able to read file using cakephp frame work on amazon web services

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, cakephp-3.0

I am using the CakePHP framework on Amazon Web Services. I am trying to open and read a file using this code -

```
$pic_file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'fb_profile_pics' . DS . $path . h($user->user_id) . '.txt');
$fb_pic = $pic_file->read(true,'rb');
```

`WWW_ROOT` var above is - `/var/app/current/webroot/`

The `fb_profile_pics` folder(location of file) is in the webroot folder in my CakePHP application.
I am not able to read this file and cannot figure what is wrong. Any help to get me going again would be awesome.

**EDIT:**

I am getting this error -

> mkdir(): Permission denied [CORE/src/Filesystem/Folder.php, line 547]

Why would aws not be granting permission when I have a Administrator policy on this instance.

Comment: This looks like a strictly Unix file permissions issue. Your AWS "Administrator policy" has no relation to your file and directory permissions on a server. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/create-file-in-folder-permission-denied

Comment: Also, that error appears to be something trying to create a directory, not reading a file like you say in your question title.

Comment: I used elasticbeanstalk to create aws ec2 which probably has set  the permission. When trying to change these permissions on this folder on there server via ftp it lets the file be created after changing permission and then sets the permissions back to 755

Comment: The error message is not related to the code in the question.